# Auto-trimming whitespace in form inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have a form with a number of inputs, each of which needs to be `Trim`med before they are processed. It would be laborious - and not very robust - to trim these on each use of the value as each is used in numerous places within the form's codebehind.

I'm thinking of doing something like this for each of my properties:

```
private string _surname
public string Surname
{
    get
    {
        return _surname.Trim();
    }
    set
    {
        _surname = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Surname = txtSurname.Text;
}
```

Even this seems pretty verbose, though. Particularly for forms which have a much larger number of inputs. Perhaps simply:

```
private string _txtSurname;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _txtSurname = txtSurname.Text.Trim();
}
```

But this doesn't have the same robustness as the first example in that, if I assign to the same property elsewhere, I might forget that I need to trim first. I feel like there should be a much more succinct way of handling this. Is there?

Comment: Amended my colossally buggered code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  The Extension Method approach, while functional isn't great from a readability perspective.  Intuitively, calling `foo.NullSafeTrim();` where `foo = null` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  However, due to the way it is implemented it doesn't.  Meh.

I agree that adding `.Trim()` to every getter and setter would be laborious.  Especially when you have to deal with all of the null checking to avoid `NullReferenceException`s.  Another option, which would make the code a bit more compact is to use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).  For instance:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
     public static string NullSafeTrim(this string value)
     {
         if (value != null)
         {
             value = value.Trim();
         }

         return value;
     }
}
```

Then you could use the following pattern:

```
private string _surname;
public string Surname
{
    get { return _surname.NullSafeTrim(); }
    set { _surname = value.NullSafeTrim(); }
}
```

There are some considerations in using extension methods, which you should be able to turn up with a search on SO.

Alternatively, you could do all of the trimming and null checking in whichever class is processing the values.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I'm stuck on .NET v2.0 for this project - however, I like this idea so I'll do something similar with a static utility class.

Do you know of any way to wrap the accessor logic up in one place so I don't have to duplicate the `NullSafeTrim` calls for every public property?

Comment: I would go with the static utility class then.  Frankly, I would use that class to either trim the values immediately before they are sent to the processor, or, as the first step in processing.  I wouldn't bother trimming every single get/set.

Comment: Cheers, think I'm just going to do with private properties and trim everything when it comes in.

Answer (score 1):

The empty get won't work, and your setting actually did not SET to the backing field!

```
private string _txtSurname
{
   get;  // problematic!
   set { return value.Trim();}
}
```

Try below:

```
public string TxtSurname
{
   get { return _txtSurname;}
   set { _txtSurname=value.Trim();}
}
```

In the Page load, do not work in the private member, use property instead

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TxtSurname = SomeText.Trim();
}
```

Comment: `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen.

Comment: which line does this exception occur? You need to check TxtSurname if it is null, it is legal that the property return null. Have a look at basic C# book.

Comment: `set { _txtSurname=value.Trim();}` `Trim` on null will throw.

Comment: if you set TxtSurname=null; it will be null; if not, this might be impossible. I think you don't know the difference of property and backing field member at all.

Comment: How can I test without clear problem formulation? I don't understand how can you have such a high reputation? Try to learn before you complain.

Comment: `TxtSurname` will throw a `NullReferenceException` when it is set to `null`. How is that unclear?

Comment: @Romoku, please ask others if this exception will be raised, I don't see any error here. Are you sure that is the line where exception pops? and also I have to ask you, did you try that? How can this be? ask others and see if this can be repeated. I don't believe!

Comment: In your setter, calling .Trim() on value when value = null will throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Going to go with this and create some separate View Models.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a new Project or it's allowed to modify the code I would create a new `Control` that derives from `TextBox`, override the `Text` property to Trim the base value, then use it instead of the Standard one

Answer (score 0):

I would provider two Properties for the form input.

```
public class FormInput
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string ValidatedSurname
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Surname)
                   ? string.Empty
                   : Surname.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the private variable and fill out the properties for your form in full. You could then provide trim() capability on both the get and set for the property and use the property to read and assign your form values instead of using the field directly.

```
private string _txtSurname;

public string TxtSurname
{
    get
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_txtSurname) ? string.Empty : _txtSurname.Trim();
    }
    set
    {
        _txtSurname = value.Trim();
    }
}
```

That way if you set or get the value without then need to worry about it being trimmed anywhere else

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TxtSurname = txtSurname.Text();
}
```

If you moved the form properties into their own class and made the field values private and the properties public (like when you develop where you use a View Model) then you would not be able to assign to the field values directly and would not risk having any untrimmed values. Of course if you're doing this then you only need the set to do the trimming.

Comment: This approach will result in a NullReferenceException.  Specifically, calling .Trim() on _txtSurname in the getter when _txtSurname is null and calling .Trim() on value in the setter when value is null.